# Passing a 2D array as parameter for a sub in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing an Assignment where we have to do a member excel sheet using data obtained from a database

I have declared the Array as

`Dim DataArray(10, 10) As Variant`

And created a Public Sub

`Public Sub FillInInfo(InfoArray() As Variant)
 //Some code here that uses the data as an Array
End Sub`

when I try to feed the Sub with the DataArray(i,j) 
`FillInInfo(DataArray)`
 I get an error[image]

Comment: Try it without the ( ) : FillInInfo DataArray

Comment: Hi, Thank you, it did work